# UICollectionView selection does not last

Tags: ios, objective-c, selection, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` I use like a tool selection container. You have many tools (the cells), when you select one, the former selected is deselected, and so on... You can only have one tool selected at a time.

The problem is that I can't manage to have the cells selected. When I tap the cell, the `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is called. I then reload the selected cell to change it's appearance (I change the `alpha` of the image) by using the `[collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]]`.

Well that reloads the cell ok, except one damn thing: in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` the cell never get the `selected` property set to `YES`! So I can never change the `alpha`because I never know when I must draw a selected cell or not.

Worse: `[collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]` is always empty!!!

I don't even mention the `collectionView:didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:` that is never called...

Well, if someone can help me understand what is going on, thanks in advance...

Comment: +1.. nice question. I have tried to resolve your issue. But I lost my control :)

Comment: Thanks for trying, you can stop for @daltonclaybrook's solution is the one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` the collection view discards those cells and creates new ones, therefor discarding the selected state of the cells.

I'd suggest a couple of different options:

1.) In `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` call `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` to get a reference to the selected cell and update it's appearance there.

2.) (My Favorite) Use a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` if you're not already, and override the method `setSelected:`. There you'll be notified when the cell is selected and you can update the appearance from within the subclass.

Comment: Thanks! I used the second one as I was working with a custom subclass. Gratz!

Answer (score 0):

With regards to selecting multiple cell at once, you should try the `allowsMultipleSelection` property `[myCollectionView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES]` The docs for that are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionView/allowsMultipleSelection

Otherwise, @daltonclaybrook's answer is sufficient.